# Getting the source HTML from an url that redirects

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get a username from a html page.
However, this page does a redirect and my function gives NULL in return.

```
function getSGname($steamid) {
/*
 * Get the user's name from SteamGifts.com
 *
 * @param bigint $steamid SteamID64
 * @return false|string SteamGifts user's name
 *
 */
    set_time_limit('30');

    // Include DOM library
    include('/lib/simple_html_dom.php');

    # create object
    $html = new simple_html_dom();

    // Build the URL to the user's SteamGifts profile
    $url = "http://www.steamgifts.com/user/id/$steamid";

    #### CURL BLOCK ####

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    $content = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    # note the variable change.
    $string = str_get_html($content);

    // Some code here to get certain div from the string
    // ...

    return $string;
}

echo "name: " . getSGname('76561197962290563');
```

Now if I replace the url with another site it works without problem.

```
$url = "http://www.bundlequest.com/index.php";
```

I'm not even getting an error though.
Why am I not getting anything back from the first url and how do I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be because the site wants to use cookies, so the website keeps redirecting because its failing to set a cookie file.

Replace this :

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

with :

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
```

You need the `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` option to set a cookie file.
`CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS` is the maximum of redirects allowed. 10 should be enough.

if it still gives you an error you can use :

```
if($errno = curl_errno($curl)) {
    echo $errno;
}
```

This will show you the error code

Answer (score 0):

Curl will follow redirects automatically. You will need to set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to false and handle the redirects manually.

Comment: Well that's the idea that the redirect is followed. I would like to get the html from the resulting page after the follow/redirect. But why is it giving me nothing?

Comment: I used `echo curl_error($curl);` this is giving me nothing as well.

Answer (score 0):

As Paul said, the solution is to set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to false.

The warning on curl_error: close $curl before display curl_error using:

```
curl_close($curl);
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I changed `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to false, but again I'm not getting any output at all from this url `http://www.steamgifts.com/user/id/76561197962290563`
I don't understand why not. Other url's do work.